# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended for INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a below query, which needs to select a row by using a column as key and return generated keys.

```
INSERT INTO t_tpms_cc_request
            (process_identifier,
             request_source_id,
             amount,
             etc_account_id,
             retry_count,
             status,
             store_identifier,
             version_no,
             next_process_time,
             composite_transaction_id,
             payment_id,
             processed_time,
             replenishment_id,
             pay_type,
             agency_id,
             response_code,
             file_id,
             request_date,
             auth_file_id,
             auth_date_time,
             merc_file_id,
             merc_date_time,
             cc_num,
             cc_expiration_date,
             merchant_id,
             ext_sys_ref,
             encrypt_cc_number,
             cc_month_cd,
             cc_year_cd,
             orig_txn_ref,
             auth_code,
             avs_code,
             cvv_code)
SELECT CC.process_identifier,
       CC.request_source_id,
       CC.amount,
       CC.etc_account_id,
       CC.retry_count,
       CC.status,
       CC.store_identifier,
       CC.version_no,
       CC.next_process_time,
       CC.composite_transaction_id,
       CC.payment_id,
       CC.processed_time,
       CC.replenishment_id,
       CC.pay_type,
       CC.agency_id,
       CC.response_code,
       CC.file_id,
       CC.request_date,
       CC.auth_file_id,
       CC.auth_date_time,
       CC.merc_file_id,
       CC.merc_date_time,
       CC.cc_num,
       CC.cc_expiration_date,
       CC.merchant_id,
       CC.ext_sys_ref,
       CC.encrypt_cc_number,
       CC.cc_month_cd,
       CC.cc_year_cd,
       CC.orig_txn_ref,
       CC.auth_code,
       CC.avs_code,
       CC.cvv_code
FROM   t_tpms_cc_request CC
WHERE  CC.order_id = ?
```

And, I have wrriten a below java code to do this:

```
String key[] = {"order_id"}; 

DataSource ds = null;  
Connection con = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
      ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
      con = ds.getConnection();
      PreparedStatement ps = 
          con.prepareStatement(insertCCRequest.trim(), key);
    ps.setString(1, OrderId);
      int i= ps.executeUpdate();
      rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
      if (rs.next()) {
         return rs.getString(1);
      }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.debug("SQL exception in RebillDao.insertCCrequest() 
                                       method..!! ");
    logger.debug("Exception cause: "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
finally {
      if(con!=null){
            con.close();
      }          
}
return "";
```

When i run this, I get below exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Please tell me the ways to fix this.

Also, Using **JDk 1.6** and **ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar**

Comment: please edit your code properly.

Comment: Do you need a semi-colon at the end of your SQL?

Comment: Did you try to use an upper case column name? `String key[] = {"ORDER_ID"}; `

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that when you use generated keys with a prepared statement, the Oracle JDBC driver adds the `RETURNING INTO` clause to the `INSERT` statement, and that  the JDBC driver is too dim to realise that the `RETURNING INTO` clause can't be used with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statements.  I get the same ORA-00933 error if I attempt to run an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... RETURNING ...` statement.

What you could try instead is a PL/SQL block where we fetch the 'old' row into a record and then use an `INSERT ... VALUES` statement with a `RETURNING_INTO` clause to insert the values into the 'new' row:

```
DECLARE
  l_row     t_tpms_cc_request%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO l_row FROM t_tpms_cc_request WHERE order_id = ?;
  INSERT INTO t_tpms_cc_request (some_column, some_other_column, ...)
    VALUES (l_row.some_column, l_row.some_other_column, ...)
  RETURNING order_id INTO ?;
END;
```

As we're returning values from this, we need to prepare this as a CallableStatement instead of a PreparedStatement, and we need to register parameter 2 as an out parameter.   We can then use this out parameter, instead of the `getGeneratedKeys()` method you're using at the moment, to return the generated key value.

Clearly this approach is Oracle-specific and won't work on other databases.  I don't know how much of an issue database portability is to you, nor whether you can return generated keys from an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement in other databases.

Comment: What a bummer. I ended up splitting the insert into select into 2 queries, I first fetch the data and then use a simple `insert into ... values`. Obviously I pay the roundtrip oracle->java->oracle etc but I find it easier to look at then PL/SQL especially until we do not have performance issues. A real shame that 4 years later we still have this problem with the driver.